# "Continue with Facebook" button doesn't work

Tags: android

Currently I have this facebook button on my login from facebook sdk that does not work only on this current phone (Redmi 4A). When on click, supposedly it will proceed to entering email and password for facebook but instead it will just display a progress dialog momentarily and go back to the login page. I've tested this with multiple phone and emulator all of them work except for Redmi 4A. At the same time I click the facebook login button this error will come up in the logcat, again only in this phone. This error does not show up in any other phone or emulator.

```
06-14 12:27:36.891 7292-7357/com.jobforhire.mobile E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8937.so
```

I tried googling it up but nothing relevant to my situation pop up and almost half of them is in chinese. I know this question might seems broad and I'm sorry for that but I have no idea what's wrong. Either it's my code or the phone itself. If I know what at fault here I can get a start on solving this. Thank you.

Comment: You can post this issue in Facebook developers `developers.facebook.com/bugs/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452894/facebook-share-dialog-not-working-correctly-in-mi-devices/42595022#42595022